# Open API POST with Path Parameter

Tags: rest, jsonschema, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am trying to write a Open API specification with Swagger-ui (swagger version 2.0) and I am not sure how to represent a `POST` parameter with a `path` parameter

`POST /ping/{text}`

My specification is as follows,

```
# this is an example of the Uber API
# as a demonstration of an API spec in YAML
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Mock API
  description: Mock API 
  version: "1.0.0"
# the domain of the service
host: api.mock.com
# array of all schemes that your API supports
schemes:
  - https
# will be prefixed to all paths
basePath: /v1
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /ping:
    get:
      summary: Ping
      description: |
        Respond to PING requests, similar to heart beat
      parameters:
        - name: path  
          in: path
          description: String input for echo service
          required: false
          type: string
      tags:
        - ping
      responses:
        200:
          description: The text passed in the request
          schema:
            type: string
        default:
          description: Empty response for request passed
          schema:
            type: string
```

And the swagger ui shows an error as follows -

```
 code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
 message:  "Not a valid parameter definition"
```

but if I change it to `in: query` the error vanishes. What am I doing wrong? or what is the right way to specify a path parameter in open API specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few changes you need to make to your document to conform to the [Open API specification](http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject).

1- The `name` field should match the path segment (ie `text`

> If in is "path", the ***name*** field MUST correspond to the associated path segment from the path field in the Paths Object. See Path Templating for further information.

2- `required: true` should be added.

> If the parameter is in "path", this property is required and its value MUST be true.

3- If you want to document `POST /ping/{text}`, `get` needs to be changed to `post`. Also the path segment (ie. `/{text`) should be added to the path.

Here is the final Swagger doc after the changes described above:

```
# this is an example of the Uber API
# as a demonstration of an API spec in YAML
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Mock API
  description: Mock API 
  version: "1.0.0"
# the domain of the service
host: api.mock.com
# array of all schemes that your API supports
schemes:
  - https
# will be prefixed to all paths
basePath: /v1
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /ping/{text}:
    post:
      summary: Ping
      description: |
        Respond to PING requests, similar to heart beat
      parameters:
        - name: text  
          in: path
          description: String input for echo service
          required: true
          type: string
      tags:
        - ping
      responses:
        200:
          description: The text passed in the request
          schema:
            type: string
        default:
          description: Empty response for request passed
          schema:
            type: string
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the specification it seems that "required" has to be true if you set "in: path".

Details can be found here: http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject

Comment: Turning the `required` to `true` still shows the same error :(